# i have this issue can someone help me thanks

Tags: reactjs

Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link,  Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import Home from './component/Home';
import Input from './form';


class App extends Component {
  
  render(){
 
    return (
      
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>

        <Routes>
        <Route path='/'  component={Home} exact />
         
       </Routes>
        
        </BrowserRouter>
      
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You stated some information but you don't explain what your issue is and what you want.

Comment: what is your query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your page is empty when you click on Home Link.
if  you are using recent version of react-router-dom, then it may look like

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home /> } />
```

In case , there is any other issue, please explain in details with error screenshot etc.
As the question does not have enough details.